# Python FileNotFoundError despite clearly having found the file

Tags: python, cmd, paradox

I'm working on a mailbomb program that randomizes images from a given directory. The code looks like this:

```
import schedule, time, smtplib, random, os, sys, socket
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Image randomization still under development

def message(subject="Python Notification",
            text="", img="", attachment=None):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    if type(img) is not list:
        img=[img]
    for one_img in img:
        path = "C:\\Users\\JoeBiden\\Desktop\\PJ\\AMP\\ImgLib"
        files=os.listdir(path)
        randPic=random.choice(files)
        img_data = open(randPic, 'rb').read()
        msg.attach(MIMEImage(img_data,
                             name=os.path.basename(img_data)))

    if attachment is not None:
        if type(attachment) is not list:
            attachment = [attachment]
        for one_attachment in attachment:
            with open(one_attachment, 'rb') as f:
                file = MimeApplication(
                    f.read(),
                    name=os.path.basename(one_attachment)
                )
            file['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment;\
            filename="{os.path.basename(one_attachment)}"'
            msg-attach(file)
    return msg

def mail():

    smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('umomghaey@gmail.com', 'PEEENIS')
    msg = message("Pizza", "Pizza", r"C:\Users\JoeBiden\Desktop\PJ\AMP\ImgLib")
    to = ("cheeseburger@gmail.com")
    smtp.sendmail(from_addr="beesechurger@gmail.com",
                  to_addrs=to, msg=msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()


schedule.every(2).seconds.do(mail)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When running in CMD I get the following error:

```
        ret = self.job_func()
  File "C:\Users\JoeBiden\Desktop\PJ\AMP\MailRandomizer.py", line 46, in mail
    msg = message("Pizza", "Pizza", r"C:\Users\JoeBiden\Desktop\PJ\AMP\ImgLib")
  File "C:\Users\JoeBiden\Desktop\PJ\AMP\MailRandomizer.py", line 22, in message
    img_data = open(randPic, 'rb').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RandImageFile.jpg'
```

To me the error seems paradoxical since it clearly shows me that it has found one of the desired files in the correct directory. That being the 'RandImageFile.jpg'

Comment: "os.listdir" only returns filenames without paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir()` only gives you the filenames, so try replacing

```py
files=os.listdir(path)
```

with something like

```py
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that results in almost the exact same error just slightly longer.

Edit: Or maybe I should try pasting it into the actual code I was going to use. I think it worked. I now have a different error but this no doubt helped. Thank you.

Comment: What's the new error message?

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'. Did you mean: 'decode'?``

I am headed for lunch now so unfortunately I cannot review this new error right now. If you have the time your input would really help but it will be an hour or so before I can reply. Thanks again.

Comment: It mighty be useful to see the full traceback of the new exception, but at a guess, `name=os.path.basename(img_data)` is probably wrong. Might you mean `name=os.path.basename(randPic)`?

Comment: ´img_data´ refers to ´img_data = open(randPic, 'rb').read()´ and therefore also ´randPic´ I'd assume. I would post the traceback but it's way too long for a comment. 

This website is incredibly restrictive in how I can ask for help for some reason. To wit, if you know a better place to ask people about this stuff, I would love that.

Comment: `randPic` contains the fully qualified file path for the image. `image_data` contains the image itself - a potentially large wodge of bytes. They are not the same thing at all.

Comment: I'd say that SO is the best place for this kind of question, but it should probably be posted as a new question, which would allow you to give the details nicely formatted. After all, the initial question has been answered, I think.